# CSS border image repeat not working

Tags: css

I have a div and I am trying to have the border to repeat an image. The image is appearing in all four corners of the div, but it is not repeating. Can anyone help?

**HTML**:

```
<div id="main" class="area"></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.area {
    position:absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 11%;
    width: 75px;
    height: 595px;
    border: solid;

    background-color:white;
    border:30px solid transparent;
    -webkit-border-image: url('media/playerAreaBorder.png');
    -webkit-border-image-repeat: repeat;

    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using simply `border-image` and `border-image-repeat` without the `-webkit` prefix?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/border-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/LejjD/4/

```
.area {
    position:absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 11%;
    width: 75px;
    height: 595px;
    background-color:white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 30px;
    -moz-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 30 repeat;       
    -webkit-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 30 repeat; 
    -o-border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 30 repeat; 
    border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 30 fill repeat;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sigma's answer is correct but you may want to take a look at using border-image-slice.  It will leave the corners as is and only stretch the middle of the border image:

```
border-image-slice: 20 20 20 20;
```

You would have to adjust the 20s in there to match your image.  It basically cuts an image into 9 regions and stretches the non-corner ones. More info:

http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image-slice.asp

Comment: Thanks your advice made me realize that I needed to actually setup 9 regions on my image.

Answer (score 0):

This is true for all prefixes like moz, webkit and o :

> Once standardized, and the support for the un-prefixed variant added,
>   the prefixed properties are dropped.

You can still include them to be compatible with older browser versions, but now most browsers support CSS3 correctly.

Also, make sure your css file and media folder are in the same folder, or else your url path is wrong.